# Database moddeling | User M:M Appointment

Tags: database-design, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I have created a database model where there is a users entity which can hold a doctor and a patiënt. These will be seperated by the "flag" attribute. The next entity is an appointment table which holds appointments. The problem I am facing is that I have a many to many relationship. To fix this I want to add another table but I don't know what i should name this and what info it should hold.

[Image of the database design](https://gyazo.com/cca1c9660111cf8edb30a6570e38dd4c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stingy with information so I will make some assumptions. Even if the assumptions are wrong on particulars, this answer should still be valid.

You have one table, Users, that contain both Doctors and Patients with a Flag field that distinguishes between them. Assumption: the flag contains 'D' for doctor or 'P' for patient.

Suggestion: create a Unique constraint/index on the Users table for the combination ID and Flag. This will greatly ease the following data integrity issues:

- an appointment can be made between a patient and a doctor, not another patient.
- on the other hand, a doctor may need to make an appointment with another doctor as their patient (this is another assumption).
- but a doctor should not be able to make an appointment with themselves (to prevent a doctor from having a fool for a patient).

The (trigger, stored procedure and/or application) code to detect and prevent those issues could get a bit complicated and would be a pain to maintain as the underlying data structure evolves over time. Here is one solution.

```
create table Appointments(
    DrID      int   not null,
    DrFlag    char( 1 ),
    PatientID int not null,
    StartTime date  not null,
    EndTime   date,
    constraint ApptDrOnly check( DrFlag = 'D' ),
    constraint ApptDrSelf check( DrID <> PatientID ),
    constraint PK_ApptUserDoctor foreign key( DrID, DrFlag )
        references Users( ID, Flag ),
    constraint PK_ApptUserPatient foreign key( PatientID )
        references Users( ID )
);
```

Because of the new unique constraint on the Users table for the ID and Flag fields, they can be used as a reference by the FK using the DrID and DrFlag fields in the intersection table. The constraint that DrFlag can contain only a 'D' limits the target of this FK to doctors only. The PatientID PK refers to the PK of the Users table so may refer to either doctors or patients. The check that DrID and PatientID cannot be the same prevents doctors from making an appointment with themselves.

There, appointments between a doctor and patient (or other doctor) with all the data integrity issues handled with no DB or app code.

If an assumption is wrong, make changes accordingly. For example, if an appointment can only be made between a user defined as a doctor and another user defined as a patient, the check( DrID <> PatientID ) can be removed and a PatientFlag field with check( PatientFlag = 'P' ) can be added.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a "userappointment" table that links users to appointments, one at a time.

Comment: 1:m relationship from both tables to 1 new table. I get that. But how do i call that one ? and what do i add other than id and the foreign keys?

Comment: Gertjan, I typically name these tables with a combination of both referenced tables, i.e. a table that describes relationships between the tables user and appointment would be called userappointment. So you are saying that you can have multiple patients and multiple doctors in a single appointment. While this is not what I generally see when I go to the doctor, you would still have all the apt-specific fields in the appointment table. The userappointment table would contain anything specific to the person's role, e.g. one doctor could be the lead doctor. Or only the keys, like you said.